# Specific Font Somehow Prohibiting Faux-Italics in Webkit Browsers

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face, webfonts

I am working with the font PT Sans Narrow, which only has regular and bold. Therefore, I need the browser to use faux italics when necessary. However, only non-webkit browsers are doing this. See this image:

[image]

However, the issue appears to lie specifically with this font, as other fonts work fine. (See this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pEVj7/) The comparison font in this fiddle was generated with identical settings on Font Squirrel.

I need to be able to simply use something such as the following, and have the browser use faux-italics if there is none available.

```
<i>My custom italic text</i>
```

P.S. I understand that faux-italics may not look the same or as good, but in this case, they are better than having no access to italics at all. Secondly, Google Webfonts is not an option due to its poor rendering in Chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be with the SVG format of the font. If you omit it, Chrome will use the WOFF format and apply synthetic italic (faux italic) on it.

I tested this by first downloading PT Sans Narrow from Google, running FontSquirrel generator on it with default settings, and testing with added italic text in the sample HTML file produced by the generator. That worked well. When I re-ran the generator with SVG option selected, the result is the same, and looking at Network pane in Chrome developer tools shows that the WOFF file is used. But when I removed other formats from the CSS file, leaving just a reference to the SVG file, the text appears upright (though developer tools still say it is PT Sans Narrow, in italic).

Checking your jsfiddle, I see that *both* the SVG file *and* the WOFF file are loaded, though as delivered text/html, but still interpreted as font files. I don’t know what is going on there. It possibly relates to internals of jsfiddle.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it does appear to be the SVG file. The problem, however, is that the SVG font format renders much better in Chrome than the WOFF - This article explains it well: http://www.dev-metal.com/fix-ugly-font-rendering-google-chrome/ Your answer does solve the specific issue I have in this question, so I'll go ahead and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

After a great deal of researching and testing, I have developed a decent alternative. While I still do not know why webkit browsers are not using faux-italics, I was able to recreate faux-italics using some CSS and jQuery. To begin, here's the HTML code I'd want to apply this technique to:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. <i>Fusce aliquam
mollis pulvinar. In tincidunt, libero vel auctor scelerisque, ligula erat
tempus neque, eu ultrices justo erat a risus.</i> Nulla facilisi. Praesent
porttitor magna sed ultricies lacinia.
```

First, I need to wrap each individual word in a span with the class `italic`. (Why every word will be addressed shortly.) I use the following jQuery code to achieve this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("i").each(function(){
        $element = $(this);

        var words = $element.text().split(" ");
        $element.empty();

        $.each(words, function(i, v) {
            $element.append($("<span class='italic'>").text(v));
            $element.append(" ");
        });
    });

    $("em").each(function(){
        $element = $(this);

        var words = $element.text().split(" ");
        $element.empty();

        $.each(words, function(i, v) {
            $element.append($("<span class='italic'>").text(v));
            $element.append(" ");
        });
    });
});
```

Then, using CSS3, I can skew the text 10 degrees, but only for webkit browsers:

```
span.italic{
    display:inline-block;
    -webkit-transform:skewX(-10deg);
}
```

And this leads me to why every word must be wrapped in its own `span`. For this to work, the display must be `inline-block`; therefore, if the italicized phrase is longer than one line, it will not wrap properly inside a paragraph unless each word has its own span.

---

### Cons

One con that I can see to using this is that if webkit browsers do begin supporting faux-italics, it will be extra slanted. Another issue is that this only works with `<i>` and `<em>` tags, and not all text that is italicized. Lastly, any images or other formatting that may be included in the `<i>` tag are removed.